# Can "Targetings" be a plural form of "Targeting" as a noun?

Tags: grammatical-number, countable-nouns, inflectional-morphology, deverbal-nouns

I understand words like "surrounding" can be "surroundings", or "binding" can be "bindings".

But is it appropriate with "targeting" as a noun?

Here is a recent headline - "UN chief calls for probe of tanker targetings"
by The Associated Press, Friday, June 14th 2019 - https://wlos.com/news/nation-world/un-chief-calls-for-probe-of-tanker-targetings

Comment: Can you give an example of "targeting" used as a noun?

Comment: What other possible plural could be possible for a countable noun?

Comment: Headlines  have their own special rules. Not that what you find in a headline is correct, but that headlines have to fit at the top of the page so they bend the rules.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to use *targeting* as a noun. (Although it's not very commonly done.)

In the following, all bold text is my own.

From [*Gender Articulated: Language and the Socially Constructed Self*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=-8z3CUhv8pYC&pg=PA113&dq=%22targetings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCvuGa__riAhUiT98KHd95AEYQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22targetings%22&f=false):

> In our corpus, women displayed the highest proportion of **self-targetings** and, in in keeping with the findings just discussed, this was also associated with narratives that women themselves raised. Although such **targetings** account for a relatively small proportion (12 percent) of the **targetings** of women overall, and they came essentially from only two families, these female self-problematizings are noteworthy in their provoking of a "dumping on" response.

From [*Governance and Ownership*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=k_-0AAAAIAAJ&q=%22targetings%22&dq=%22targetings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCvuGa__riAhUiT98KHd95AEYQ6AEIQzAF):

> The sample identified consists of 356 independent **targetings** of 146 firms over the seven-year period. These **targetings** include both proxy proposals and nonproxy **targeting**.

From [*International Criminal Law: Cases and Materials*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Y3ZRAQAAIAAJ&q=%22targetings%22&dq=%22targetings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCvuGa__riAhUiT98KHd95AEYQ6AEITjAI):

> What is critical under the Convention, that **targetings** actually be made against the types of human groups listed in Article II or that there be a genocidal intent to destroy such a human group in whole or in part?
>
> . . .
>
> For example, **targetings** by combatants during war have been and can be used for purposes of elimination or to produce "psychological coercion."

From the [*Michigan State Journal of International Law, Volume 20*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=G2guy91dAQgC&q=%22targetings%22&dq=%22targetings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCvuGa__riAhUiT98KHd95AEYQ6AEIUjAJ):

> With respect to U.S. use of armed force in Pakistan to target those who are lawfully targetable under the laws of war and during a *de facto* war that his migrated into parts of Pakistan, some might claim that the United States would need the consent of Pakistan for each such **targeting**, that the **targetings** are violations of Pakistani sovereignty.

Comment: Good answer. The plural is avoided by most online dictionaries (Wiktionary is as usual brave/foolhardy enough to buck the trend) and some avoid giving a separate entry for _targeting_.  But I think the word should now be considered to have been deverbalised and countified.

Comment: The targetings will continue until morale improves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the application of it is very rare as shown by [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=target%2Ctargets%2Ctargeting%2Ctargetings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctarget%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctargets%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctargeting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctargetings%3B%2Cc0)

"Targeting" as a noun is the name of something that targets. For example, a military weapon might feature *automatic targeting*, and this could be abbreviated to simply "targeting".

> **Example**
>   The targeting on this weapon is off by 2mm.

This would not be plural, as "targeting" sufficiently describes the process. It is not the same as "bindings", for example, as this is what we call the *material* used in the process of binding, so logically you can count it because it refers to *items*, not the process. The process of targeting does not produce anything except identifying a *target*, which of course can be plural in the form *targets*.

You could use "targeting" as a noun on plural items:

> The targeting needs calibrating on all these weapons.

The same goes for the word "binding". When referring to the *process*, the singular form is used for multiple items:

> The binding on these books is terrible.

The only time you would use the plural "targetings" is if you were collectively referring to multiple, *unrelated* instances of targeting.

For example:

> 75 percent of all targetings of women fit this description.

This is talking about individual instances where women were targeted by different people. Because they were unrelated, they are countable.

If the multiple instances of targeting were by the same person or device, or were related on some way, perhaps part of some coordinated attack, then the singular suffices:

> The targeting of women by advertisers.

Because the implication here is that advertisers target women in the same way, their targeting can be used singularly. This is why the use of the plural is so rare and on the ngram above is almost a flatline.

Comment: The OED certainly lists *targeting* as a noun, not just as a verb — gerunds and present participles being verbs. [One paywalled citation](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197838) they provide for the noun is “1976  *National Observer* (U.S.) 27 Nov. 5/1 —  NCEC laid out $350,000 for candidates in 1976. That paid for 64 polls in 32 separate congressional districts and for computerized precinct targeting and analysis in more than 40 districts.” No citations for the plural of that noun are included, but since it's now a noun rather than a verb, it’s perfectly possible to construe a regular plural.

Comment: @tchrist can you link to an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: @tchrist an example of the plural being used, but it's ok i found one. It's very rarely required. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @tchrist I assume that indefinite count usage / inflection for plural form are the criteria OED use for deciding on (deverbal) nounness?

Answer (score -2):

No. If you use the gerund form of a verb as a noun, then you cannot add *s* in it because *targeting* works as an abstract noun.